# How do I add items to my associative array?

Tags: php, arrays

I defined my array

`$data = array();`

added 1 item:

`$data['response'] = true;`

Now I want to add multiple items at once like:

`$data["picUpload" => $pPicUpload, "Album1" => $Album1, "Album2" => $Album2];`

But i'm getting this error:

```
parse error, expecting `']''
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $data = array("picUpload" => $pPicUpload, "Album1" => $Album1, "Album2" => $Album2);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it in multiple lines like:

```
$data['new0'] = 'value0';
$data['new1'] = 'value1';
```

or use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) (will overwrite colliding keys):

```
$data = array_merge($data, array('new0' => 'value0', 'new1' => 'value1'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add one by one, or use `array_merge` method.

```
$data["picUpload"] =$pPicUpload;
$data["Album1"] = $Album1;
$data["Album2"] = $Album2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you're using is incorrect. You need to use the array_merge functionality

```
$data = array_merge($data, array(
  "picUpload" => $pPicUpload, 
  "Album1" => $Album1, 
  "Album2" => $Album2
));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array_merge($data, Array("picUpload" => $pPicUpload, "Album1" => $Album1, "Album2" => $Album2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
$data["picUpload"] = $pPicUpload;
$data["Album1"] = $Album1;
$data["Album2"] = $Album2;
```

Comment: because I knew it was possible to do it as I described and I wanted to learn why it wasn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = array("picUpload" => $pPicUpload, "Album1" => $Album1, "Album2" => $Album2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$data = array("picUpload" => $pPicUpload, "Album1" => $Album1, "Album2" => $Album2);
```

Comment: It is not what Paul is asking :)